# Get first line of text of an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, multiline, spannable, bold

In my app I have a multiline EditText and I have to achieve a layout in which the first line of this EditText contains bold text, while the other lines have regular formatting. I've looked up several ways to do this, but I keep seeing answers like "use two separate EditTexts", which is unfortunately not an option here. I also found an answer which said I have to get the index of the first line break ("\n"), but this doesn't work in my scenario either, since there are no hard line breaks and the text automatically gets put on the next line.

Is there a way to retrieve the first line of an EditText so I can make this test bold with a Spannable? And if not, is there another way to only make the first line of a multiline EditText bold?

Comment: so basically the line break is tied up with the length of the View where the text is being rendered ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you're saying, but there are indeed no real line breaks and it is just how the text is rendered in the EditText. I have to get the first line from how it is rendered.

Comment: You can use something like `editText.getLayout().getLineVisibleEnd(0) - 1` to get the index of the last visible character on the first (0th) line, then apply your span to that.

Comment: I misremembered the details for `getLineVisibleEnd()`; you don't need the `- 1`. This turns out to be a little tricky, though, 'cause bolding that text can change its total width, which might end up pushing a bold word to the next line. I haven't really decided how to handle that yet, but this should give you an idea of what this suggestion would entail: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fcUJZWZDnGrYDkg5Uy_eDNJZw5-IFUsG/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: That might be even trickier than I first realized, as `EditText`'s `Layout` is behaving rather unexpectedly, and is leading to pixel-level discrepancies in where the first soft break should be in certain cases. However, there is a `Paint` method that allows fake bolding, which basically draws the regular font a little heavier, and doesn't cause the width change. If that's acceptable, it'd be much easier. This example is in a custom `EditText`, just to show how that could work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UUFKgoJYe_Hi06R702F11NKiTWOgkjox/view?usp=sharing.